# Как создать действие обновление?

Tags: java, android

Мне необходимо действие обновление, как в браузере (к примеру, chrome). Пользователь тянет вниз,  при этом появляется круг. Как это можно создать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реализации такого действия есть стандартный компонент в библиотеке поддержки *Support Library v4* начиная с ее версии 22.1.0. Называется он -
 `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Ссылка на [документацию и официальный гайд](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html) по использованию.